# Create "Choose Language" Cookie from Select Dropdown

Tags: redirect, select, cookies, drop-down-menu

I have a "Choose your language" modal that will appear when a user first visits the site.  They can then select the language they want and a cookie will then be created and stored.  When the user re-visits the site, they will be automatically redirected to the language of their choosing.  The cookie is being created when I select an option, but it's contents are equal to "%2F" and no redirect occurs.  I imagine this is because I'm not calling some kind of "pageload" function and everything is within the bind() function, but I'm lost on where to go from here.

Here is a page with the below code:

http://www.watsu.se

Here is what I have so far:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('#language-select').bind('change', function () {

      var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value

      if (url) { // require a URL

          $go = $.cookie('lang', url, {expires: 7}); // create cookie from select URL

               if ($go){ //if the cookie exists
                     window.location = url; // redirect
                       }
               else {
                // do nothing until cookie is created
                    }

               }

      return false;
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution from a very kind fellow internet user.  I wasn't really telling it to go there in the first place.  Here it is in case someone else needs this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var usrLang = $.cookie( 'lang' );
    (usrLang === null) || ( window.location.href = usrLang );
});
```